# Question about Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

The equations and related theorems confuse me. So I try to prove them myself. Can someone check if I am correct?

Suppose $f$ maps an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ into $\mathbb{C}$. Let $E$ be the set of all $(x,y)$ for which $x+iy\in\Omega$. Then $E$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Denote the real part and imaginary part of $f$ by $u$ and $v$, respectively; that is, $f=u+iv$. Define mappings $F:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $U:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $V:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$U(x,y)=u(x+iy)\text{,}\quad V(x,y)=v(x+iy)\text{,}\quad\text F=(U,V)\text{.}$$

If $f$ is differentiable at $z\in\Omega$, then
$$\tag{1}\frac{\lvert f(z+h)-f(z)-f'(z)h\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert}=\frac{\lvert[u(z+h)-u(z)-u'(z)h_1+v'(z)h_2]+i[v(z+h)-v(z)-v'(z)h_1-u'(z)h2]\rvert}{\lvert h_1+ih_2\rvert}$$
tends to $0$ as $h=h_1+ih_2\rightarrow0$.

If $F$ is differentiable at $X=(x,y)\in E$, then
$$\tag{2}\frac{\lVert F(X+H)-F(X)-DF(X)(H)\rVert}{\lVert H\rVert}=\frac{\lVert(U(X+H)-U(X)-\partial_xU(X)h_1-\partial_yU(X)h_2,V(X+H)-V(X)-\partial_xV(X)h_1-\partial_yV(X)h_2)\rVert}{\lVert(h_1,h_2)\rVert}$$
tends to $0$ as $H=(h_1,h_2)\rightarrow 0$.

If we have
$$z=x+iy\text{,}$$
$$\tag{3}\partial_xU(x,y)=\partial_yV(x,y)\text{,}$$
$$\tag{4}\partial_yU(x,y)=-\partial_xV(x,y)\text{,}$$
$$\tag{5}u'(z)=\partial_xU(x,y)\text{,}$$
$$\tag{6}v'(z)=\partial_xV(x,y)\text{,}$$
then (1) is equivalent to (2) by the definition of norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and hence $f$ is holomorphic at $z$ if and only if $F$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$.

Suppose $f'(z)$ exists, then
$$\begin{aligned}
f'(z)&=\lim_{h_1\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h_1)-f(z)}{h_1}\\
&=\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{u(z+h_1)-u(z)}{h_1}+&i\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{v(z+h_1)-v(z)}{h_1}&=u'(z)&+iv'(z)\\
&=\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{U(x+h_1,y)-U(x,y)}{h_1}+&i\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{V(x+h_1,y)-V(x,y)}{h_1}&=\partial_xU(x,y)&+i\partial_xV(x,y)\\
&=\lim_{h_2\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+ih_1)-f(z)}{ih_2}\\
&=\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{u(z+ih_2)-u(z)}{h_2}+&i\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{v(z+ih_2)-v(z)}{h_2}\\
&=\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{U(x,y+h_2)-U(x,y)}{ih_2}+&i\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{V(x,y+h_2)-V(x,y)}{ih_2}&=\partial_yV(x,y)&-i\partial_yU(x,y)\text{.}
\end{aligned}$$
This proved (3)-(6).

> **THEOREM** If $f$ is holomorphic at $z=x+iy\in\Omega$, then $F$ is differentiable at (x,y)$.

> **THEOREM** If $F$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$, $U$ and $V$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation, then $f$ is holomorphic at $x+iy$.

Comment: Is "holomorphic at a point" defined?  Generally, we prove that if the C-R equations hold on an open set, then $f$ is holomorphic on that set.

Comment: *“...then (1) is equivalent to (2) by the definition of norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and hence $f$ is holomorphic at $z$ if and only if $F$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$.”* No, that isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's are conflicting definitions (as seen from the comments you received) regarding the phrase *'holomorphic at a point'*:

- Some people say $f$ is holomorphic at a point $z_0$ if there is an open neighborhood $\Omega_0$ of $z_0$ such that at each point $z\in \Omega_0$, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ exists (briefly, $f$ is complex-differentiable at each point of $\Omega_0$).
- Some people say $f$ is holomorphic at a point $z_0$ if the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$ exists (briefly, $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0$).

I learned and use the second, and find the first to be confusing language, but apparently it is standard. It is now a standard exercise (essentially as you've tried to show) to prove the following theorem:

> With your notation, $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ if and only if $F$ is Frechet-differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}(y_0,y_0),\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0).
> \end{align}

While your proof has the right idea, I dont like it in the sense that you use symbols before proving their existence. For instance, when proving "$f$ is differentiable at $z \implies$ $F$ is differentiable at $X=(x,y)$", you write down the symbol $DF(X)(H)$ even before proving that the linear transformation $DF(X)$ exists.

Comment: For a more conceptual viewpoint of the role of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, see (the first half of) [Generalizing the Analyticity of holomorphic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4116765/568204) and [Derivative of a Complex Function as a $\Bbb{C}$-linear Transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3885292/568204). The point is that the Cauchy-Riemann equations encode the conditions for an $\Bbb{R}$-linear transformation to become $\Bbb{C}$-linear.

Comment: +1. Hi there peek-a-boo - those are interesting links about the compatibility of $\Bbb C$-linear structure. Is that related to the standard representation of $\Bbb C$ as: $$x+iy\simeq\begin{pmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{pmatrix}$$Which is often used to "explain" Cauchy-Riemann?

Comment: @FShrike yes that's right (letting $z=x+iy$, the multiplication map $\zeta\mapsto z\cdot \zeta$, on $\Bbb{C}$ induces a linear map $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, whose $2\times 2$ matrix representation with respect to standard bases is what you wrote. Another way of saying it is that if we view $\Bbb{C}$ as a $2$-dimensional real vector space, then that's the matrix representation relative to the $\Bbb{R}$-basis $\{1,i\}$).

Comment: Ah, here's the rub. Why, in your second link, do you get to say: "since *every* $\Bbb C$-linear transformation has the matrix representation you describe"? That is a curious restriction

Comment: @FShrike hopefully my previous edited comment explains it. But in case it's still not clear: $(x+iy)\cdot 1=x+iy=x\cdot 1 + y\cdot i$, so the first column of the matrix is filled up with $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$. Next, $(x+iy)\cdot i=-y+ix = (-y)\cdot 1 + (x)\cdot i$, so the second column of the matrix representation is filled up with $\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\end{pmatrix}$ This is how we find the matrix representation of the complex-multiplication-by $z$ map relative to the basis $\{1,i\}$ when viewing $\Bbb{C}$ as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I think I was having a dissonance with matrices qua $\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C^2$